Reposurgeon fails to mirror svn
Update figured the problem I needed to configure svn to store passwords, see the answer for details.
Problem description follows
I've got a svn database that needs to be converted to git, so about as basic use case as it comes.
I'm using WSL / ubuntu and have pulled the 4.31-1 version of it with apt, I also tried getting the 5.0 from the repository but that didn't make any difference.
The SVN database does not follow the standard format, it looks like this:

Repotool fails right away trying to do the mirror, why? Git-svn does work, but reposurgeon was supposed to be "better".
omannisto@olli-lt:~/repotest2$ repotool initmake AltiumComponentLibrary svn git
repotool: a Makefile already exists here.
repotool: generating a stub options file.
repotool: generating a stub lift file.
repotool: generating a stub map file.
omannisto@olli-lt:~/repotest2$ nano Makefile
omannisto@olli-lt:~/repotest2$ make
rm -rf AltiumComponentLibraries-mirror
make AltiumComponentLibraries.svn AltiumComponentLibraries.opts AltiumComponentLibraries.lift AltiumComponentLibraries.map
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/omannisto/repotest2'
repotool mirror http://omannisto@10.4.0.44:8008/svn/oxford/AltiumComponentLibraries AltiumComponentLibraries-mirror
Authentication realm: <http://10.4.0.44:8008> Authorization Realm
Password for 'omannisto': **********

repotool: executing "/usr/bin/sh -c svn info --show-item=revision  http://omannisto@10.4.0.44:8008/svn/oxford/AltiumComponentLibraries": exit status 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:71: AltiumComponentLibraries-mirror] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/omannisto/repotest2'
make: *** [Makefile:62: AltiumComponentLibraries-git] Error 2
omannisto@olli-lt:~/repotest2$ nano Makefile

EDIT svn info command output
omannisto@olli-lt:~/repotest2$ svn info --show-item=revision  http://omannisto@10.4.0.44:8008/svn/oxford/AltiumComponentLibraries
Authentication realm: <http://10.4.0.44:8008> Authorization Realm
Password for 'omannisto': **********

37557
omannisto@olli-lt:~/repotest2$


The image contained additional text which you haven't transcribed. I don't know if it's important, but at least the status message from repotool with the (badly quoted?) sh -c command line looked like a possible clue.

That's all it says, "exit status 1". I started getting a bunch of error messages about kwalletd which probably is not related, I get the same for git svn which still logs in okay. Should maybe reinstall wsl.

Fine. I add the kwalletd errors, and the repotool make output. kwalletd is just a red herring, I was not getting that before trying to get unrelated qt5-using packages to work and it's just (trying to) cache the password. I modified make to remove the output file 1st as repotool errors out if it's present. make calls repotool mirror, which is causing the error, so now we just have a lot of unrelated fluff there.

@tripleee Yeah, thanks for the help. I didn't do anything wrong, the problem is that reposurgeon doesn't let you define the svn password anywhere and starts svn non-interactively so it can't ask me for password either. To fix that I needed to install gnome password manager and configure svn to use it obviously in virgin WSL install neither was done. Error spam from kwallet kind of pointed towards the problem but it does not appear on a clean WSL install, installing some other packages made it happen.

If you found a solution, please post an answer - don't edit the answer into your question. FWIW, you can use Subversion without any password manager if you're fine with the password being stored in plain text in your home dir, see this question.

@Friedrich Hm. Last time I asked a question I couldn't answer it until some 24 or 48 hours had passed. Ok, I'll copy it there now then. That information is obsolete, svn will not store plaintext passwords unless it's compiled in or you use some official script to do it, but it's probably easier just to add the lines to the config and server files and installe gnome-keyring

Ugh, still one more gotcha, gnome-keyring doesn't activate automagically on wsl.

The problem is that repotool fires svn import using "sh -c" non-interactive session, this will duly fail since it cannot ask me for the database password. There's no way to define the password with reposurgeon. This would be a non-issue if this was a linux-box that's been using subversion for ages, but it's a virgin WSL installation for porting company svn database over to git.
To fix the issue I installed gnome-keyring, kwallet was causing problems (error spam, wants to add ~95 packages) in wsl. With gnome-keyring installed and editing the  ~/.subversion/config and servers to allow saving passwords using gnome-keyring, the password was saved after the first time it was asked and things started to work.
To wit, add/edit line
# password-stores = gnome-keyring

in ~/.subversion/config [auth] section
and add/edit lines
# store-passwords = yes
# store-auth-creds = yes

in ~/.subversion/servers [global] section
Installing gnome-keyring requires some extra effort on WSL, since it's essentially headless linux. First we install it like normal:
sudo apt install gnome-keyring -y

There are some problems with gnome keyring not actually starting properly, one way to get around it is to put this into the end of your .bashrc:
echo 'db' | gnome-keyring-daemon --unlock

With this the repotool mirror works fine, with or without using the makefile created by repotool initialize. You need to create a keyring when first using the password and after that you need to unlock it, once a session.
